# Using the Run to Line command in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

When I click on the `Run - Run to Line` menu item (or press `Ctrl + R`) in my PyDev 2.8 + Eclipse Kepler  + Windows 7, the `Set Next Statement` command is executed.

How do I execute the `Run - Run to Line` command?

**EDIT**

After upgrading to Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 and PyDev 4.4.0 the problem is still there